# TikZ: Making names of intersections global

Tags: tikz-pgf

Inside a foreach loop, I create points and lines between them,
intersect them, and name their intersections. The mechanisms for that are
provided by the intersections library.

Because I'm inside the local scope of a foreach loop, I need to use constructs like

```
\path[name path global=AB] (A) -- (B);
```

to make the name `AB` global if I mean to access it later from outside the for-loop. My question is: To name intersections (in this case, `Z`, where `AB` and `CD` intersect), typically (outside a loop), I use constructs like

```
\path[name intersections={of=AB and CD, by=Z}];
```

But inside a foreach I have the same problem: The name `Z` will be local. I have not been able to figure out how `name intersections` can be made to bind variables associated with its `by` arguments globally.

I can also provide same code if my problem descriptions is not clear.

Comment: Why not just provide all the relevant information from the get-go? A MWE would serve well here.

Comment: @Troy: It's just a matter of time/effort. I mean to provide one eventually anyway but I'm currently working with a deadline so I'd rather not devote time to that now unless it's deemed necessary.

Comment: @Troy I see your point now in insisting on an MWE though, because that could have revealed what I was doing wrong earlier. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have this problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i [count=\ni] in {1,2,...,5}{
    \draw[name path=AB\ni, xshift=2*\i cm] (0,0)--++(45:2cm);
    \draw[name path=BA\ni, xshift=2*\i cm] (0,2)--++(-45:2cm);
    \path[name intersections={of={AB\ni} and {BA\ni}, by={Z\ni}}];
}

\draw (Z1) circle (2pt) -- (Z5) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, I see. I see what the problem was now. The key is that one needs to use `of={AB\ni}` instead of `of=AB\ni` (which I used yet which surprisingly does not work, even though `name path=AB\ni` above does). So this certainly solves my problem, thank you. Not sure what the best way is to turn this into something helpful to others.

Comment: @anonymous Next time provide a MWE becuase I decided to test with different path names by chance. To test names outside foreach it's not necessary.

Comment: Shape names are always globally defined foreach doesn't matter.